# TypeError: middleware is not a function Error | v3 Migration Guide on React Redux Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

I was using these packages but Suddenly I got this error on middleware composition when I created a new `react` app using *`create-react-app`*.  I have the following packages. Can you please explain to me what am I missing here?
**HELP**

Looked up to this guide as well

[Image Showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sTTf.jpg)

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.4.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

**`index.js`**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createFirestoreInstance } from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from "react-redux-firebase";

import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import createReduxStore from "./store/createReduxStore";

import App from './App';

const fbConfig = { // hidden for debug };
const rrfConfig = { userProfile: 'clients' };
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
const store = createReduxStore()

const rrfProps = {
    firebase,
    config: rrfConfig,
    dispatch: store.dispatch,
    createFirestoreInstance
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
            <App />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**`createReduxStore.js`**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const initialState = {}

export default () => {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware([thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)])
    )
}
```

**`rootReducer.js`**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    firestore: firestoreReducer,
    firebase: firebaseReducer,
})
```

**Solution**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createFirestoreInstance,getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'

import { rootReducer } from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import App from './App';

const fbConfig = {};
const rrfConfig = { userProfile: 'users' };
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
//firebase.firestore();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})))

const rrfProps = {
    firebase,
    config: rrfConfig,
    dispatch: store.dispatch,
    createFirestoreInstance
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
            <App />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass array of middlewares as an argument to the `applyMiddleware`. You should pass each middleware as an separate argument, try this:

```js
export default () => {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase))
    )
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried with and without the Array. But It looks like the firebase initialization and injecting firebase instance through the applyMiddleware() function is the conflict.  Because i created the store in a separate file and imported in the **index.js** file. I will update the question with the solution. Thank you so much for your effort.  

Lastly working code doesn't have Array args to the applyMiddleware().